# Strange behavior during variables assignment in Scala

Tags: scala, variables

How can I define variables inside if-block ?

```
if ( 2 > 1  ){
    val t = 6
}
print(t)
```

This simple code returns error : not found: value t

Comment: It's a scope problem. The variable is only in scope for use within the block defined by the brace brackets

Comment: What would happen the day the `if` was false?

Answer (score 1):

Your code's `t` variable is only defined within `if` block. So you can use it only inside this block. One reason for this behavior is a question: Which value has `t` when the condition of the `if` statement is false.

If you want to use the `t` variable outside this scope you can do the following:

1. Put `if` block in the assigning like this:

```
val t = if (2 > 1) 0 else 1
```

2. Use `var` keyword to make the `t` mutable and define it before `if` block with the default value:

```
var t = 1

if (2 > 1) {
  t = 0
}
```

In any case, you need a value for `else` case to be able to define the `t` variable.